# How to setup completely automated deployment pipeline in UCD from Dev till Prod?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, udeploy, urbancode, ucd

I'm trying to find Jenkins pipeline feature in UCD where deployment is automated without any click. Usually in UCD I found that(from online resources) people use to chose environment and versions manually. Can anyone help me how I can do that?

Comment: UCD = urban code ?

Comment: Yes, UCD = Urban code deploy

Comment: Are you able to use jenkins to invoke actions in urban code? Are you using github or something like that?

Comment: Yes...Basically I'm using jenkins job which will pull source code from github to post artifact to UCD and trigger UCD job in dev

Comment: Do you need  that your jenkins job choose dynamically the environment configurations instead of a human doing it previously? Are you using this plugin https://github.com/UrbanCode/ibm-continuous-release-plugin/blob/master/Jenkins-Pipeline-Support.md or how are you invoking commands on UCD?

Comment: I'm using https://developer.ibm.com/urbancode/docs/integrating-jenkins-ibm-urbancode-deploy/ method to invoke UCD job from jenkins

Answer (score 0):

UCD is completely different from Jenkins. It does not have Jenkins like pipeline (declarative/scripted) features. UCD is more controlled, environments oriented and secured deployment tool. It doesnt contain beautiful visual pipeline features which Jenkins has.

Comment: Thanks for reply, Basically I need to trigger build & deploy automatically in all environment. Problem with Jenkins plugin with UCD is posting artifact is must but I need to post artifact only in Dev and use same artifact in higher environment.